# How can I set invisible area in ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

ListView Image

[image]

Hi. I'm using ListView in my Android app.
I want set my listView like above image.

App user only can see LEFT and CENTER area only.
and I want set some component in RIGHT area, but This area must not be visible.

How can I do this?

Here is my current layout xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="8dp" >

<!-- LEFT AREA START (VISIBLE) -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- LEFT AREA END -->


<!-- CENTER AREA (VISIBLE) -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<!-- CENTER AREA END -->


<!-- RIGHT AREA START (INVISIBLE) -->
    <!-- I don't know what to do -->
<!-- RIGHT AREA END -->
```

Comment: set your right area layout as android:visibility="gone"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this element for RIGHT layout:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

About this element:

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout
>   purposes

Answer (score 1):

You can set android:visibility="gone" for the right area

Answer (score 0):

There is one property of widget invisible with which you can occupies space but control is not showing check following code

```
<!-- LEFT AREA START (VISIBLE) -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `visibility="gone"` on any view element, in a layout xml file, to make it disappear from the user's sight.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for sliding layout which will be visible once button is click or any other event performed, till than that layout will be hide and other 2 layout will occupy full space of device.

You should check this [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html)

Here is nice demo for SlidingPaneLayout.

[Link 1](http://www.incredibleandros.com/slidingpanel-android-example/)
[Link 1](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/exploring-slidingpanelayout/)

[image]

You can make it slide from right to get your desired output.